# Which one is more profitable to farm? Higher priced items or more farmability items?

Tags: growtopia

Say there are 2 items. Let's ignore gem. Also let's ignore time spent on planting because that's miniscule.

For example, wooden platform vs grass. Wooden platform seed worths 65/WL. Grass worth 200/WL.

However, grass grow easily. The seed ratio per refarm is 1.8. For wooden platform, the seed ratio per refarm is 1.2. That is, 200 seeds planted get all the blocks, and destroy all the blocks and I get 240 seeds. With grass, I got 1.8*200, I got 1.6 360 seeds.

Which one I should farm to max out WL per hour?

Okay so we have 2 items. We have farmability ratio f, price p. Which one is more profitable per hour for the same number of blocks destroyed?

Well. Assume seed shows up in blocks 25% of the time. Always. For all goods. I am not sure if the math is correct here. Also presume that difference of farmability depends only on differences of number of blocks produced.

To produce 200 seeds of grass, I will need to destroy 800 grass blocks. However, I want to keep my original grass of seeds. Now the math gets fussy. So there are extra blocks that I should destroy just to keep the original seeds intact. The number will be less for grass and for wooden platform.

I would say the number will be f/f-1 * 800 grass blocks. So for grass, I need to destroy 1.8/.8 times 800 grass blocks.

For wooden platform I need to destroy 1.2/.2 * 800 wooden platform blocks.

For some things to be profitable the number of platform blocks to be destroyed must be more than the price ratio.

So item 1 should be more profitable than item 2 if and only if

(f1/f1-1)/p1 is less than (f2/f2-1)/p2

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you accounting for growing time? Also, if you know the seed ratio and amount of blocks dropped per tree, you should be able to find the seed drop rate from blocks instead of assuming 25%